# How can I avoid entering a character in an EditBox in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to prevent the user from entering a character in an `EditText` a second time, for example, if you enter the number zero, it's OK but if you want to enter the number zero for the second time, that action should be canceled.

In other words, I don't want the user to write 00.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: For this, you need to implement  editext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()

Comment: Do you want the user to only enter unique characters or do you only want to cancel if the same character is typed twice in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
   EditText editText  = new EditText(this);
   InputFilter inputFilter = new InputFilter() {
       @Override
       public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            //Write your logic to remove the zero
            //remove the zero here and return it.
            return null;
       }};

   editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{inputFilter});
```

Comment: This will not allow the user to enter the Zero at any time ...Already there are some predefined filters in the android like datetime filter allcaps filter etc. Check out and let me know ..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. One more question, How do I remove the character? Thanks again

Comment: It is with return "";

Comment: `    InputFilter inputFilter = new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                //Write your logic to remove the zero
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(source);
                String s = stringBuilder.toString().replace("CharToReplace","");
                return s;
            }
        };`

Comment: if you return "" , then always the edit text will be empty. Filter your character and then return it

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This implementation deletes surplus character, but you'll get an idea:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int length = s.length();
            for(int i=1;i<length;i++){
                if (s.charAt(i-1) == s.charAt(i)) {
                    mEditText.setText(s.subSequence(0, i));
                    mEditText.setSelection(i);
                }
            }
      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
  });
}
```